# changing the default port no of tomcat in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, port

Hi all I'm trying to change the port number of my Tomcat server installed on Ubuntu. For this I have changed the file `server.xml` and made the following changes:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But the problem is that whenever I try to open the `localhost:8081` it is working fine but when I tried to open `localhost:8080` but it is still accessible. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Secondly when I made the default port 80 then tried `localhost:80` or `localhost` then it was not accessible. Again, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the listener still up on port 8080, you'll want to verify that there isn't a connector defined for that port, and that no other tomcat instances are running.

---

It's likely that the cause of the issue with port 80 is that low ports require root privileges to bind, and tomcat, by default, runs as a non-root user.  The way to get around this is to use authbind.

```
apt-get install authbind
touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
chown tomcat6:tomcat6 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

Then, modify the config file for tomcat to enable authbind support.

```
nano /etc/default/tomcat6
```

I believe the setting for authbind is near the bottom of the file.

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to check the instances of the tomcat.

Comment: @codeomnitrix `ps aux | grep java` will give you the running java processes, you're looking for any running under the tomcat6 user.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution http://beginlinux.com/server/ubuntu/changing-the-port-on-tomcat and it worked for me. All you need to do is to confirm which ports are already in binding then change the port number in the server.xml file of tomcat. Then you need to restart tomcat to make sure change gets implemented.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect iptables rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport http -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8081
```

better not to running Tomcat as root(80 port need root permission).

Comment: ok thanks ooshro. i will try this one. but it would be better for me if you please explain the above command a bit i mean to ask what the various switches are intended to. actually i am not a professional developer rather a student so.  still thanks for your answer

Comment: @codeomnitrix Rahter go the authbind way. There you won't be running as root, but would still be able to have port 80 for your Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

personally I change it in the /srv/apachexxx/conf (or wherever you installed it, inside the conf/ folder) in the file server.xml look for

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

and change the port. You also need to change the shutdown ports else you will get a warning, due you cant use same ports (in case you will have more than one tomcat running)